# What does the empty parentheses mean after 'require' declaration in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In `Node.js` I see sometimes a declaration like this:

```
var App = require('express')();
```

What do the empty brackets `'()'` at the end mean?

I am suspecting the declaration above is equivalent to something like:

```
var Express = require('express');
var App = Express();
```

Is that right?

Comment: You are correct. Require returns a function which is called using the `()`.

Comment: Also check out this blog post : http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/

Comment: Syntactically, by definition, the `()` could do only thing, which is to invoke a function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As James already answered the module returns a function which is than invoked in this manner.

Here a simple code sample to make it easier understandable.

```
function a() {
    function b() {
        alert('Alert me!');
    }
    return b;
}
a()();
//alerts 'Alert me!'
```

Answer (score 3):

Essentially the `express` module is returning a function. The empty brackets call the function so now `App` is the result of the returned `function`.